# use relationship in model accessor in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Suppose I have a `Course` model like this :

```
class Course extends Model
{    
        public $primaryKey = 'course_id';

        protected $appends  = ['teacher_name'];

        public function getTeacherNameAttribute ()
        {
            $this->attributes['teacher_name'] = $this->teacher()->first()->full_name;
        }

        public function teacher ()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'teacher', 'user_id');
        }
}
```

And in the other hand there is a `User` model like this :

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

        public $primaryKey = 'user_id';

        protected $appends = ['full_name'];

        public function getFullNameAttribute ()
        {
            return $this->name . ' ' . $this->family;
        }

        public function course ()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Course', 'teacher', 'user_id');
        }

}
```

As you can see there is a `hasMany` relationship between those.

There is an `full_name` accessor in User model.

Now I want to add a `teacher_name` accessor to `Course` model  that uses it's `teacher` relations and gets `full_name` of teacher and appends to `Course` always.

In fact I want whenever call a `Course` model, it's related teacher name included like other properties.

But every time , when call a Course model , I got this error :

```
exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Trying to get property of non-object' in D:\wamp\www\lms-api\app\Course.php:166
```

That refers to this line of Course model :

```
$this->attributes['teacher_name'] = $this->teacher()->first()->full_name;
```

I do not know how can I solve that and what is problem exactly.

Comment: `$this->teacher()->first()`, i wonder, does it require `->first()` or not.

Comment: It doesn't. `$this->teacher->full_name` will do the trick.

Comment: If you access relationships inside of custom model accessors, you will run into an N+1 query situation whenever you load a collection of `Course`s. This is because Eloquent will execute the `teachers` relationship query on each instance of the parent `Course` model when it appends the custom `teacher_name` attribute.

Answer (score 6):

Yikes some interesting answers here.

FYI to those coming after me- `getFooAttribute()` should *return* the data, and *not* modify the internal attributes array.

If you set a new value in the attributes array (that doesnt exist in this model's db schema) and then attempt to save the model, you'll hit a query exception.

It's worth reading up the laravel docs on [attribute accessors/mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators) for more info.

Furthermore, if you need to access a related object from within the model (like in an accessor) you ought to call `$related = $this->getRelation('foo');` - note that if the relation isnt loaded (e.g., if you didnt fetch this object/collection with eager loaded relations) then `$this->getRelation()` could return null, but crucially if it is loaded, it won't run the same query(ies) to fetch the data again. So couple that with `if (!$this->relationLoaded('foo')) { $this->loadRelation('foo'); }`. You can then interact with the related object/collection as normal.

Comment: "getFooAttribute() should return the data, and not modify the internal attributes array" - the link you shared to laravel docs is leading to this:
```public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";
}```
You are right for eager loading. Reaching for relations inside accessor is terrible way to go. If you do something like Course::all() and that returns 100 courses, 100 queries will be started just to fetch teacher relation.

Answer (score 1):

`$this->attributes['teacher_name'] = $this->teacher()->first()->full_name;`

Should be

`$this->attributes['teacher_name'] = $this->teacher->full_name;`

First thing is that you want to reference the relationship, so loose the brackets `()`, and because the relationship is `belongsTo`, you will have one user / teacher returned. So you don't need the `first()`.

We haven't seen your fields but probably you will have to change:

`return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'teacher', 'user_id');`

to

`return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'foreign_key', 'other_key');`

where `foreign_key` and `other_key` are the primary keys that you need to make the join on.

Check this link from the documentation for reference:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

Comment: I tried your solution. but when calling a course model, that return this : `{
  "course": {
    "teacher_name": null,
    "course_teacher": null
  }
}`

Comment: That could only mean two things. Either there is no defined `teacher` for the `course`. Or the relationship definition is wrong.

Comment: I sure that `foreign_key` and `other_key` is correct but I do not know why that returns `null`

Answer (score 0):

the right way to do this is:

**COURSE**

```
public function setTeacherNameAttribute ()
{
    $this->attributes['teacher_name'] = $this->teacher->full_name;
}
```

Comment: because you are defining the value of the attribute .. not fetching .. if your fetching then just do `return $this->teacher->full_name;`

Answer (score 0):

100% working for me.

I have one to one relationship between Order and Shipment. I have to add the accessor of shipments table column from orders table.

```
function getOrderNoAttribute()
    {

        $appendText = "OR100";

        if($this->orderShipment()->first()) {
            $appendText = $this->orderShipment()->first()->is_shipping === 1 ? "ORE100" : "OR100";
        }

        return $appendText . $this->attributes['id'];

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This error is only object data to array use or array data to object data use.

example::

$var->feild insted of $var[feild]

$var[feild] insted of $var->feild

Answer (score -1):

You should use return for accessors . something like this :

```
 public function getTeacherNameAttribute ()
    {
        return $this->teacher()->first()->full_name ?? '';
    }
```

maybe a course hasn't teacher.